# How does one remove the separator line / shadow between status bar and main screen?

Tags: java, android, background, themes, statusbar

In my application, I'd like to keep status bar but make its background be the same as the main screen.

So I created a custom theme to set application background:

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Shelves" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_shelf</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then put it in manifest:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Shelves"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".HelloWorld"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And get this one:

[image: Screen shot 2]

Everything is okay except the separator line between status bar and main screen. I thought that it's because of text view padding, so I set it to zero but nothing changed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World");
    setContentView(tv);
    tv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Here is what I am expecting http://i1178.photobucket.com/albums/x370/BinhNguyen84/device1.png. I couldn't put it in my question due to max link restriction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot the 'seperator' is actually the status bar shadow. I'm going from memory here but I think you can disable it with:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Apologies if the attribute name is slightly wrong, as I say, going from memory but I think it's right.

Comment: Genius. How can you find out this param. Thank a ton, it took my whole this afternoon. :)

Comment: It's buried in the doc's, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_windowContentOverlay